# extract fun:bad result in erlang module using Tsung

Tags: erlang, protocol-buffers, tsung

I'm writing a test using tsung extended by erlang modules, but I always get the same error and don't even send anything to the server.

the error is:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 7-Oct-2019::21:12:17 ===
      ts_search:(7:<0.181.0>) found module name: "test"
=INFO REPORT==== 7-Oct-2019::21:12:17 ===
      ts_search:(7:<0.181.0>) found function name: "authenticate"
=INFO REPORT==== 7-Oct-2019::21:12:17 ===
      ts_search:(4:<0.181.0>) extract fun:bad result <<57,...,49>>
```

My tsung session is:

```
<sessions>
    <session name="authenticate" weight="1" type="ts_raw">                         
       <request subst="true">
         <raw data="%%test:authenticate%%" ack="local"></raw>
       </request>
    </session>
</sessions>
```

My module is:

```
-module(test).

-include("test_protobuf.hrl").

-export([authenticate/1]).

authenticate({Pid, DynData}) ->
   test_protobuf:encode_msg(#'Authenticate'{user="user", pass="pass"}).
```

And I'm using the erlang compiler: https://github.com/tomas-abrahamsson/gpb

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tsung function that calls your `authenticate/1` function, [`ts_search:extract_function/5`](https://github.com/processone/tsung/blob/develop/src/tsung/ts_search.erl#L101-L114), expects a return value of either an integer or a string, but your function is returning a binary. Change it to

```
authenticate({Pid, DynData}) ->
    binary_to_list(test_protobuf:encode_msg(#'Authenticate'{user="user", pass="pass"})).
```